# Issue with passing double-quotes as a string in c#

Tags: c#, string, escaping, double-quotes

I need to pass the below path as URI.

```
 https://api.mytrade.com/oauth/accesstoken?grant_type=auth_code -d "code=DBvmp1o9"
```

I used the below solutions to implement escape charecter for the double-quotes which resulted in Internal Server error.

Solution 1: `string URI = "https://api.mytrade.com/oauth/accesstoken?grant_type=auth_code -d \"code=" + accessCode + "\"";`

Solution 2 (Verbatim string literal): `string URI = @"https://api.mytrade.com/oauth/accesstoken?grant_type=auth_code -d ""code=" + accessCode + "";`
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What are you passing the string *to*?

Comment: space and quotes aren't things you see in uris; did you uri-escape it? (space would be + or %20; quotes would be %22; equals would be %3d, etc

Comment: @lc: I'm passing the string to Weclient.UploadValues() method.

Comment: @Marc: No. but all my other API calls work fine, except this API call requests double-quotes for the "code" field to be sent.

Comment: @aceventura without proper uri escaping the behaviour is undefined. The fun thing about undefined behaviour: you can't trust it to always be undefined in the same predictable ways. I would guess the `=` is the main part contributing to broken-ness

Comment: I agree with you Marc. Shall try to implementing using uri-escape.

Answer (score 0):

if you put escape character you should not use double "//" .. try using single "/" .. it will be work .. or use simply @ before the double quotes.

Comment: / doesn't need escaping in C# terms; and in http urls, // is very much  desired

Answer (score 0):

I tried the code you provide, and the result is:
https://api.mytrade.com/oauth/accesstoken?grant_type=auth_code -d "code=DBvmp1o9

Lacking double-quotes at the end. I bet that because the last double-quotes wasnt escaped by verbatim. `+""` considered empty string instead of double-quotes. Your solution 2 should be:

```
string URI = @"https://api.mytrade.com/oauth/accesstoken?grant_type=auth_code -d ""code=" + accessCode + @"""";
```

Or

```
string URI = string.Format(@"https://api.mytrade.com/oauth/accesstoken?grant_type=auth_code -d ""code={0}""", accessCode);
```

Given the `accessCode` hardcoded to "DBvmp1o9", the output of both code as i tested should be: https://api.mytrade.com/oauth/accesstoken?grant_type=auth_code -d "code=DBvmp1o9"

This is my best shot. If you get the same output but still getting the Internal Server Error, then you can go with implementing using uri-escape as you said.

Comment: No Luck @har07, still getting the Internal Server Error. The immediate window shows -d \"code=dKBFuf1e\""

Comment: strange, -d \"code=dKBFuf1e\"" seems like excess double-quotes at the end now.

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer a verbatim string with escaped double-quote:

```
string URI = @"https://api.mytrade.com/oauth/accesstoken?grant_type=auth_code -d \""code=accessCode\""";
```